# JAX-RS (RestEasy) problem when passing id to update an object

Tags: java, microservices, jax-rs, wildfly

I'm new to Jax-RS and I have to create this service to manage some users, I have created:

1. UserDAO: java class to do DAO operation.
2. User: Java entity with hibernate annotations
3. UserService: Jax-Rs server.

Here i post the code, then the question:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private String username;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

Then i have the DAO:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("psUnit");

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

@Override
public void create(User user) { 
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(user);   
    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}

@Override
public User read(int id) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    User u = em.find(User.class, id);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return u;
}

@Override
public void update(User user) {
    User old_user = this.read(user.getId());
    old_user.setUsername(user.getUsername());;
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(old_user);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
        
}

@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(user);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    
}


public List<User> findAll() {       
    TypedQuery<User> results =  em.createQuery("from User", User.class);
    return results.getResultList();     
        
}
```

And at the end of the service class:

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {
    UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl = new UserDaoImpl();

    @Path("/create")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void createUserFromJsonRequest(User s) {
        System.out.println("**Received JSON request**");
        System.out.println(" Name : " + s.getUsername());

        userDaoImpl.create(s);

    }
    

    @Path("/delete")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteUser(User s) {
        userDaoImpl.delete(s);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    
    
    @Path("/update")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response update(User s) {        
        userDaoImpl.update(s);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    

    @Path("/getall")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() {
        List<User> users = userDaoImpl.findAll();
        return Response.ok(users).build();

    }
    
    
    @GET
    @Path("/findbyid")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
        User retrieved = userDaoImpl.read(id);
        System.out.println(retrieved.toString());
        return retrieved;
        
    }
```

If I want to create a user then I make this simple POST request using insomnia:
[Post request to create a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSWdL.png) .

It will create the row in the corresponding DB, the problem is that when I try to update a user, so I do this request:

[update request to change username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZiH3.png) the id that goes through the java application is **0**, not the one I passed (3 in the image) and I don't really know why [id is 0, not 3 as I passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmbxN.png) (the passed username is correct by the way)

What I'm doing wrong? I'm a little bit confused, should I implement DTO/Mapper? is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You need at least a setter for the id. The deserializer will call the setter to set the id. For a GET, you will also need the getter.

Comment: Solved, Thank you :), it was such a stupid question but i was really blocked yesterday.